# Jquery alternate way of calling :first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using cheerio which is like jQuery for node.js, but `:first` is not available.

I want to use something like

```
var title = $(this).find('td:not([rowspan]):first').text();
```

So when I am grabbing data I can ignore all td elements that have `[rowspan]`. For most of the data it looks like

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>somethingelse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>somethingelse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>somethingelse</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- SOMETIMES THERE IS AN UNRELATED TD IN THE FIRST -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:center; background:#ffdacc; textcolor:#000;"><b>3</b></td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>somethingelse</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Since there are no classes I need to grab the `$('td:nth-child(1)')` or  `$('td:first')` element, but in some cases its actually the second element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **.eq(0)**:

```
var title = $(this).find('td:not([rowspan])').eq(0).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` and not `:first`:

```
var title = $(this).find('td:not([rowspan]):first-child').text();
var title = $(this).find('td:not([rowspan]):first-of-type').text();
```

If the above both doesn't work, you need to loop through to satisfy the stuff and once done, you can break.

Comment: `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` is related to parent, not document

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use .eq(0) to get the first element of the colection

```
$('td').eq(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `this` is referring to the `tr` then you can use [.first()](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#first)

```
var title = $(this).find('td:not([rowspan])').first().text();
```

Comment: Ok I will try it again, I must have goofed, but I did try that. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nth-child(1)`

```
var title = $(this).find('td:not([rowspan]):nth-child(1)').text();
```

Comment: I did but the results are not the same.